# Bootstrap 3 mobile keyboard unlocks navbars

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbars on my site using bootstrap 3 (header and footer).

The navbars work perfectly for all navigation, until the iOS keyboard is brought up. When the keyboard is brought up, it `un-fixes` the position of the navbars and makes them appear `static` (you can scroll them around and they just look like they're overlayed on the page).

Sample Footer code:

```
<div class="footer navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
    <div class="navbar-header"><div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" style="height: 1px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <div class="btn-group dropup" style="width:100%;">
          <!--somestuff-->
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whats the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860205/1612605

Just hiding my siteContent, which resolved the issue. since there's no content to scroll around to while editing text. I could also include it to remove my header as well, but for now that's not causing an issue so I'll leave it in.

```
$(document).on('focus','input, textarea, select',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#siteContent').hide();
    },20);
});
$(document).on('blur','input, textarea, select',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#siteContent').show();
    },10);
});
```

Comment: makes sense, nice approach

Answer (score 2):

this is lightly covered here:  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards

> **Virtual keyboards**
>
> Also, note that if you're using inputs in your modal or navbar, iOS
>   has a rendering bug that doesn't update the position of fixed elements
>   when the virtual keyboard is triggered. A few workarounds for this
>   include transforming your elements to position: absolute or invoking a
>   timer on focus to try to correct the positioning manually. This is not
>   handled by Bootstrap, so it is up to you to decide which solution is
>   best for your application.

Here's an example of the "transforming your elements to position: absolute" approach:

http://dansajin.com/2012/12/07/fix-position-fixed/

Comment: the 2nd link doesn't appear to work

Comment: weird- it's working for me, let me know if it continues to not work.

Comment: It may be my network. This guided me in the right direction, but I ended up following another posts' answer since it was covered there for exactly what I needed. Thanks!