# iOS keyboard adds extra padding to html on input focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

iOS seems to be adding extra padding to HTML element when input is focus, even if the entire page says, don't overflow,don't add padding, just don't do anything, iOS is like F**K you!

this is when input is not selected

[image: input not selected]

[image: when input is focused]

this is probably the 100th post on this topic.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-wu-27lkf?fontsize=14)

2019 and this is still an issue, spend 2 days reading stack overflow and webkit website and nothing to seems to be working.

here is a list of related topics that don't work

[position: fixed doesn't work on iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-on-ipad-iphone/)

[iOS input focused inside fixed parent stops position update of fixed elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199072/ios-input-focused-inside-fixed-parent-stops-position-update-of-fixed-elements/)

[iOS Safari css position fixed when textarea is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873553/ios-safari-css-position-fixed-when-textarea-is-focused/)

[iOS iPad Fixed position breaks when keyboard is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492613/ios-ipad-fixed-position-breaks-when-keyboard-is-opened/)

[How do I stop my fixed navigation from moving like this when the virtual keyboard opens in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273098/how-do-i-stop-my-fixed-navigation-from-moving-like-this-when-the-virtual-keyboar/)

[Safari in ios8 is scrolling screen when fixed elements get focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001977/safari-in-ios8-is-scrolling-screen-when-fixed-elements-get-focus/)
[How to stop mobile safari from setting fixed positions to absolute on input focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987153/how-to-stop-mobile-safari-from-setting-fixed-positions-to-absolute-on-input-focu/)

[Fixed/absolute positioning neglected in iOS when focusing on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824876/fixed-absolute-positioneing-neglected-in-ios-when-focusing-on-input)

Comment: where is the padding? that just seems to be highlighted

Comment: @brk i've added background colors to `html {red}` and it's by default `0 padding, 0 margin` but when the virtual keyboard shows up on input focus it adds a scroll to the page and that extra padding from `html` tag

Comment: @brk the red part should not even be visible in the viewport, since `.app` is full height and width blocking the view on `absolute position`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing all height properties off the body tag? I had this issue and I removed

```
    body {
     height: auto; // I removed this and it fixed mine
    }
```

I would experiment by removing any

```
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      position: relative;
      // height: 100%; // delete this
      // min-height: 100%; // delete this
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

Also make sure you clear your cache.